# How to prevent OutOfMemory exception in tomcat (limit memory per war file)?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

If a `tomcat` webserver is running multiple `*.war` applications, and one of those apps cause a `OutOfMemory` exception, this will take down the whole tomcat server.

Question: is it possible to prevent this? Eg assign a maximum memory limit to each war file, so that only this application will be shut down (or restartet)?

Comment: You can't set memory per war. Xmx is set to only to the entire tomcat.

Comment: **Java Melody** is a tip. https://dzone.com/articles/java-memory-and-cpu-monitoring-tools-and-technique

Comment: _is it possible to prevent this?_ No. If the webapps are not linked to each other, you can run as many Tomcat instances as webapps you have (1 for 1). By _instance_ I mean completely separated Tomcat (TOMCAT_BASE = TOMCAT_HOME) or _real_ instances (1 TOMCAT_HOME and X TOMCAT_BASE, which allow to mutualize some part without the overhead of upgrading X times)

Comment: @EugèneAdell how much would you consider the overhead of X TOMCAT_BASEs in one tomcat installation, compared to alle war files inside one tomcat server? Is it then possible to eg restart only one of the tomcat BASEs on a crash, without affecting others even though all are running in the same tomcat home?

Comment: Of course it will take more memory (minimum X * 500mB ?). Yes, you could then restart one instance after a crash without disturbing the others.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Tomcat runs in a single JVM and web applications share memory as well as all other resources including CPU, thread-pools, network I/O etc.

The simplest solution to manage memory per web application is to run separate Tomcat instances. The memory overhead of doing this is a few 10s of MB assuming you reduce other resource allocations accordingly. For example, if you have a single Tomcat instance with 200 threads in the thread pool and you split that into 4 Tomcat instances if you allocate a total of more than 200 threads across all four instances you will need more memory for the extra threads.

Also keep in mind that you will be using resources less efficiently. In a single instance if one web application experiences a spike in use it can take advantage of resources (e.g. threads) the other web applications aren't using. If each web application has its own instance, that can't happen. This is the price you pay for isolating web applications.